# Joda Time - parse just 4 digiti year

Tags: jodatime

I'd like to parse out just the year, getting a exception if it's not valid.

I've tried:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy")
```

But this works for other than a four digit year.  ("1" is valid, as if 500000). I realize both of those are technical valid, but for my app I really want a "yyyy" exactly.

I could try to look at make sure that it's 4 digits before calling, but rather keep it inside of DateTimeFormat.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,
-Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create formatter with [**DateTimeFormatterBuilder**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and method [**appendFixedDecimal**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFixedDecimal(org.joda.time.DateTimeFieldType,%20int))

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
     .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.year(), 4)
     .toFormatter();
```

In this case formatter will throw exception for non 4 digit years

**Or** if you are using Java 8, then you can use [**DateTimeFormatter**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) from JDK.

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter =   
   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy");
```

JDK's formatter throws exception for such dates